# Upload Multiple Rows to Teradata via VBA ODBC Connection

Tags: sql, vba, excel, teradata

I have the following VBA code that I use for `select` statements for Teradata that works.

```vb
Sub Item_Review()

Dim strsql As String

strsql = Worksheets("SQL").Range("b3")

    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Item_Review").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    Debug.Print strsql
    CommandText = SplitMeUp(strsql)

    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Item_Review").Refresh

End Sub
```

However, I tried changing the *strsql* from a `select` statement to an `insert into` statement.  When I run the VBA nothing happens. I hit the button and I do not get any update notification nor do I get an error notification.  When I view the table in Teradata, I can see that it has not been updated.  Any thoughts?

```vb
Sub Item_Add()

Dim strsql As String

strsql = "insert into Table_1  (Item_id, NOTE, date, Work_STATUS) values ('Item_1','Testing ','2014-01-01','Worked');"

    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Item_Add").ODBCConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    Debug.Print strsql
    CommandText = SplitMeUp(strsql)

    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Item_Add").Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try double quotes instead of single quotes inside strsql?

Comment: I get an error in the VBA editor if I try to double quote.

Comment: How about two single quotes instead- same error?

Comment: @ Daniel Marcus I tried two single quotes and nothing.

Comment: @Portland RunnerThere is no sub that has `On Error Resume Next` and `ActiveConnection.Errors()` doesn't return anything either

Answer (score 0):

Simply you are not executing any action query. Consider doing so with an ADO connection object which you can build from your OLEDB or ODBC workbook connection (choose appropriate one).

```vb
Sub RunQuery()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle    
    Dim connstr As String, strsql As String
    Dim conn As Object
    Const adModeReadWrite = 3

    ' OLEDB CONNECTION STRING (PREFIXES REMOVED)
    connstr = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Connections("Item_Add").OLEDBConnection.Connection, -
                      "OLEDB;", "")
    ' ODBC CONNECTION STRING (PREFIXES REMOVED)
    connstr = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Connections("Item_Add").ODBCConnection.Connection, _
                      "ODBC;", "")

    strsql = "insert into Table_1  (Item_id, NOTE, date, Work_STATUS)" _
              & " values ('Item_1','Testing ','2014-01-01','Worked');"

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    With conn
       .ConnectionString = connstr
       .Mode = adModeReadWrite
       .Open                   
       .Execute strsql       
    End With

    MsgBox "Successfully ran query!", vbInformation     

ExitHandle:
    Set conn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to run as long as I had a table connected to the connection.

1)So I went to the data tab in Excel
2)Clicked on existing connections
3)Selected the query
4)Imported the data to a table

Once I did this, the SQL would execute on the refresh.